# How do I use -analyzeduration from ffmpeg with FFmpegDecoder.framework from mooncatventures?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have been playing with the RtspPlay1 from mooncatventures to try and stream a live stream from an ffmpeg streaming source with as little delay as possible.  The problem is even when I modify the code to indicate the -analyzedelay 0 flags in RtspPlay1 it does not seem to do anything.  I came to this conclusion because the delay is the same on my computer without the -analyzeduration 0 flag as the iOS device.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Here is the command I am trying to emulate on the iPhone:
ffplay rtp:///224.1.1.1:11326 -analyzeduration 0

Here is the modified code I tried with RtspPlay1:

```
forward_argc=1;

forward_argv[1] = "-analyzeduration";
forward_argv[2] = "0";
//forward_argv[3] = "30";
//forward_argv[4] = "-fast";
//forward_argv[5] = "-sync";
//forward_argv[6] = "video";
//forward_argv[7] = "-drp";
//forward_argv[8] = "-skipidct";
//forward_argv[9] = "10";
//forward_argv[10] = "-skiploop";
//forward_argv[11] = "50";
//forward_argv[12] = "-threads";
//forward_argv[13] = "5";
//argv[14] = "-an";
forward_argv[3] = cString;

NSLog(@"glflag %@\n ",[parms objectForKey:@"glflag"] );
if ([parms objectForKey:@"glflag"]!=@"1") {
   forward_argv[4]="0";
}else {
forward_argv[4]="1";
}


forward_argc += 4;
```

Comment: rtspplay1 is an open source app based on ffplay but it isn't ffplay. given that 0 never seems to work, try higher values. Also I am not sure that parameter works in rtspplay1, we abandoned that code some time ago in favor of using apple api code to accomplish the same thing with less abstraction. That said which delay are you trying to minimize startup or avsync.

Comment: I am trying to minimize startup delay.

Comment: Michelle, do you example code of how you are doing things now?

Comment: yes but its way to much to talk about here, I suggest joining our Facebook users group, see www.streammore.tv